# Getting confirm dialog text from FF4 programatically

Tags: javascript, firefox, dialog, firefox4

I'm trying to find a way to get the text of the new confirm dialogs in Firefox 4 programatically. So far by hooking into the main dom document I can read the XULElements and click OK and Cancel but I can't seem to find anything containing the text that is shown by the dialog. Does anyone know of a way how to do this either through javascript or some other means? The dialog is open at the time so that's something to take into consideration.

Comment: Sounds like a difficult task.

Comment: It is, pretty much wading through the firefox DOM using javascript and C#, it's that they changed confirm dialogs to these wonky looking grey boxes that makes it a pain to update my software to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough time I have figure it out, to do so you set document to the firefox DOM that contains xul elements and use `document.activeElement.parentNode.parentNode.textContent` to get the value of the open confirm dialog.